# Permutation & combination problem,Platform problem,

Tags: combinatorics

At a platform there are 3 gates numbered 1,2 and 3.In how many ways can 100 people get inside the platform?

Given that only 1 may enter through 1 gate at a time.

Ans:102!/2!

I need the explanation
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the 100 people in a row, and insert 2 separator between them. Then the people before the first separator will enter through gate 1, the people between the two separators will enter through gate 2, and the other through gate 3.

The number of options to place 2 identical separators and 100 people in a row is $\dfrac{102!}{2!}$.

If the people are identical, the number of options are $\dfrac{102!}{100!2!}={102 \choose2}$

Comment: p.s:thanks for the answer :)

Comment: one doubt: why cannot it be 3^100.because each person has 3 options and there are 100 people.

Comment: @AJ_ because the order doesn't matter. Think about a simplified case with just three people. The case 1,1,2 and 1,2,1 could be defined as different (and then the number of options is 3^3) or the same (then the answer will be 5!/3!).

Comment: if the order matters then he answer will be 102!/2! right?